# bad system image in emulator

Tags: android-emulator, eclipse-adt

im gettting this report on the console while I'm trying to run the app on eclipse kepler, and the emulator doesn't open, any idea whats wrong or any advice to fix it ?

```
[2015-01-05 17:53:02 - Emulator] NAND: bad arg: 14/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/sdk/platforms/android-10/images//system.img
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just uninstall the andorid sdk, and then i restart eclipse and i got it working again.
i think the problem was : it was needing to update to the latest sdk tools.